# What Unicode control characters are safe to when handling text?

Tags: unicode

For one stage of internal text processing I need a special character. What control characters are (relatively) safely to use, because they do not normally appear in text.

I refer to text as it would appear in human-readable text files and sites like SE or Wikipedia.

Example: I assume 0+0095 (MW Message Waiting) and U+0094 (CCH Cancel Character, = delete last character) are not normally stored in text files as they refer to transmission.

Counter-example: It would not be wise to use U+000A (New Line, LF), because this would normally appear in text.

Wikipedia has a list of all [Control Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes).

**Suggested Answer** (so your answers can refer to differences)

Codes I would *not* use:

- U+0000 NUL (might be used as an end-of-string character)
- U+0009 HT Horizontan Tabulation
- U+000A LF Line Feed
- U+000B VT Vertical Tabulation (although I have never seen it in use)
- U+000C FF Form Feed (used by RFCs, for instance)
- U+000D CR Carriage return
- U+001A SUB Substitute (may be used as EOF indicator)
- U+0082 BPH Break Permitted Here
- U+0083 NBH No Break Here
- U+0085 NEL Next Line

But all the others look fine to me (SO Shift Out, DC1 Device Control One, US Unit Separator, PU1 Private Use One, ...).

Comment: Whether any one particular character may or may not appear in a file depends on where its content comes from. Every character defined by Unicode can legally be used anywhere it makes sense. Perhaps your best bet is to use a byte sequence which is illegal in UTF-8 or whatever other particular encoding you want to use.

Comment: "Private Use One" sounds like a good choice. @deceze's concern is of course true, but maybe you can remove potential occurrences of this character in a preprocessing step when importing the texts, such that in the end all PU1 characters are the ones you inserted.